# JAXB XML object to a single inline string (pass it to DB)

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb

I am using maven and jaxb to process an inbound XML file and query a DB. Request is the inbound XML and response is the outbound XML.  There is a  (many possible formats here)  within the XML file (child of the main).  I need to create a single string with all of the contents and tags of ObjectData.  The DB takes this  tag as a single parameter.

What is the most efficient and useful way to have an entire XML node be placed into a string with tags included?

Thanks!